# jQuery .submit() doesn't send input submit in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, submit

I have a little jQuery (1.6.2) script that changes the input submit value to "Sending..." and prevents it from working without a selected image.

```
$('form#upload').submit(function(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();

  var image = $('input[name="image"]');
  var upload = $('input[name="upload"]');

  if (image.val())
  {
    upload.val('Sending...');
    this.submit();
  }
});
```

`image` is an input file, `upload` is the input submit. It works fine in Chrome, but Firefox (5.0) does not send the input submit in the POST, only the image, which causes my server side script to fail. I could work around that, but I'd like to know if I can fix that and I can't seem to find anything on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply remove the unconditional `event.preventDefault();` and only call it if the form should **not** be submitted.

```
$('form#upload').submit(function(event)
{

  var image = $('input[name="image"]');
  var upload = $('input[name="upload"]');

  if (image.val()) {
    upload.val('Sending...');
  }
  else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I wrongly assumed that I needed to prevent the default from happening first.