# jQuery submit function doesn't send input submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I was looking for answer for my question but I didn't found solution. Here is similar topic [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066399/jquery-submit-doesnt-send-input-submit-in-firefox) but I have different code and I don't know how to fit answer from this topic to my code.

Here is my problem. I'm sending my form with id `order_form` to `test.php`.
Every form value is sending proper except `input submit`. My script is based on checking that `<input id="sendform" type="submit" value="ORDER PRODUCT" name="sendform"/>` is send.

Below is code that I use to send form.

```
$("#order_form").submit(function() {

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "includes/test.php",
           data: $("#order_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
                alert(data);
           }
    });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

And here is content of test.php

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Here is examle form because my form is extremaly big.

```
  <form id="order_form">
      <input type="text" name="w2b" value="abc"/>
      <input id="sendform" type="submit" value="ZAMAWIAM" name="sendform"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: the order form as is realized in html would be helpful.

Comment: `avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.` use `e.stopPropagation()` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML5 forms when you are passing through parameters and variables to the ajax functions the value data from "Submit Inputs" isn't passed through. So if you have a form set up as :

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="foo" value="bar">
<input type="submit" name="submitTest" value="Hello World!">
</form>
```

The value of "submitTest" isn't being sent through. The only thing that gets sent through is the parameter "foo" with the value of "bar". "submitTest" only submits the form and executes your ajax call in this case.

To fix this just add a hidden element in the form.
Now it would look this

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="foo" value="bar">
<input type="hidden" name="sendform" value="ZAMAWIAM">
<input type="submit" name="submitTest" value="Hello World!">
</form>
```

This will send through the value to your ajax call and you can use it for whatever you might need it for.

Comment: So there is no way to to send that and I have to rewrite my code.

Comment: Well that is exactly what I did. Your advice was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you wrap your jquery code in

```
$(function(){
//code here 
});
```

Again Dont forget to prevent Default Event , Below is a rewrite of your jquery code

```
$(function(){
$("#order_form").submit(function(event) {

event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "includes/test.php",
           data: $("#order_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
                alert(data);
           }
    });//end ajax

});//end on submit

});//end jquery
```